# docker-compose container name use dash (-) instead of underscore (_)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-desktop

I always used docker-compose on Ubuntu, in this environment containers are named with underscore:

- <project>_<service>_<replica>

But now, I switched to Windows 10 (using Docker Desktop) and naming convention has changed:

- <project>-<service>-<replica>

[image]

I don't know if this is OS dependent but it's a problem. My scripts are failing because they rely on containers named with underscores.

Is there a way to customize this and use underscore instead of dashes?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This naming convention difference appears to be a difference between Docker Compose versions v1 (Python) and v2 (Go). The latest docker/compose repo that is packaged with Docker Desktop is the golang version in the [docker/compose v2 branch](https://github.com/docker/compose/tree/v2). Looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/0062703bea796eca5b5f78a4779fa166cc18619c/pkg/compose/compose.go#L36) in this branch:

```golang
// Separator is used for naming components
var Separator = "-"
```

The python branch source code is using the `_` naming convention for components, [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/5db8d86f127848367e4d721e992c188923c89d42/compose/container.py#L260) for example:

```py
    def rename_to_tmp_name(self):
        """Rename the container to a hopefully unique temporary container name
        by prepending the short id.
        """
        if not self.name.startswith(self.short_id):
            self.client.rename(
                self.id, '{}_{}'.format(self.short_id, self.name)
            )
```

As to solving this, you may want to uninstall the compose included with Docker Desktop and revert to a 1.28.x version. The [compose readme](https://github.com/docker/compose/tree/1.28.x#using-pip)  says you can use `pip install docker-compose` to install. The compose docs have a section about upgrading this and commands to migrate to v2: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#upgrading but your question suggests you want to stay with the `_` v1 naming convention.

As mentioned in comments, the following options retain the compose compatibility:

1. use `--compatibility` flag with `docker-compose` commands
2. set `COMPOSE_COMPATIBILITY=true` environment variable

Other doc links:

- Backward compatibility is discussed here: https://github.com/docker/compose#about-update-and-backward-compatibility
- Docs/Readmes suggest installing [compose-switch](https://github.com/docker/compose-switch) for translating docker-compose commands
- If you instead want to upgrade to v2 on Ubuntu and modify scripts: https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/#install-on-linux

Comment: Great answer, thanks to you I found that `--compatibility` flag maintains the v1 behavior: `docker-compose --compatibility up -d`

Comment: You can also use `COMPOSE_COMPATIBILITY=true` environment variable instead of `--compatibility` option.

Comment: @jawira glad it's helpful and I'll add those options the answer for completeness

Comment: If you need to preserve the env var suggested above for using with `sudo` you can do `--preserve-env=COMPOSE_COMPATIBILITY` after doing the `COMPOSE_COMPATIBILITY=true`

Comment: Since I already started the service and had a container with hyphens, I had to `rm` the container for `--compatibility` to work. Stopping it wasn't enough.

Comment: I specified the container name in my `docker-compose .yml` using `container_name: project-db` to fix this problem.

Comment: In current v2 branch you can see that the separator was moved to api.go: https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/v2/pkg/api/api.go#L546

Answer (score 12):

After the last Docker Desktop update, "docker-compose" automatically downgraded to v1.

Now there is a new option to select your "docker-compose" version, which was disabled by default:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just to save people from insanity: **Docker Desktop packaging appears to be glitchy.**

I am running Docker Desktop 4.3.0 (71786) on Windows 11, with the WSL2 backend.

[image: docker desktop]

Here are the docker-compose information from my terminal:

```
% which docker-compose
/usr/bin/docker-compose
% ls -al /usr/bin/docker-compose
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 Dec   9 19:52 /usr/bin/docker-compose -> /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/docker-compose
% sha256sum /usr/bin/docker-compose
35dd89af6820dc111991f4c9b8ed7b253fefa33a30392fed506490ddc2553e91 /usr/bin/docker-compose
% docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.2.1
```

Docker Desktop has been freshly installed. With this version, `_` is used as the separator character.

Now, let's switch to the same version of docker-compose, downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases):

```
% sudo wget -q https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.2.1/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -O /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v2.2.1-gh
% sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v2.2.1-gh
% sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v2.2.1-gh /usr/bin/docker-compose
% ls -al /usr/bin/docker-compose
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Dec   9 20:18 /usr/bin/docker-compose -> /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v2.2.1-gh
% sha256sum /usr/bin/docker-compose
68a3bb67bd25abf0f6da2a9d171a873ac182c3cc1c51fb4866e7770675823d2f  /usr/bin/docker-compose
% docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.2.1
```

With the GitHub version, `-` is used as the separator character, as expected.

This means that Docker doesn't just repackage the binaries available on GitHub, but make their own builds from a source tree that is different from the one tagged with the same version on GitHub. (Thanks [@tentative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69519102) for pointing out the line of code defining the separator!)

And some final notes:

- docker-compose from other recent versions of Docker Desktop used `-` as expected.
- It is not the first time that switching between `-` and `_` happened. Anecdotally, I remember having the very same issue a few months back, but after upgrading it went away.
- If you don't destroy your environment, `docker-compose up` will use the existing container names. This means that it may take you a while to notice the change.
- I have reported this to the [GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12433) of Docker for Windows. As of end of 2022, the issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

We noticed that the  command

`docker compose up`
and
`docker-compose up`

would give either _ or - depending on which one you used.

Comment: That's because these are 2 different commands : `docker-compose` (with a dash) was a third-party tool, now integrated into Docker as a subcommand `docker compose` (with a space). These are two different implementations, which have a different convention.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but it works:

Ubuntu/Linux

```
# Revert to docker-compose: 1.29.2

sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo wget -q https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 -O /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v1.29.2-gh
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v1.29.2-gh
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v1.29.2-gh /usr/bin/docker-compose
ls -al /usr/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose --version
```