# Can't Get Rid of Old Docker-Compose Services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Two weeks ago I created a docker-compose.yml file to start two services, but this week when I try to start those services Docker appends a "-1" to the service name. I am using Docker Desktop on a Windows 10 machine. Here is my yml file:

```
services:
  pgdatabase:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=####
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=####
      - POSTGRES_DB=ny_taxi
    volumes:
      - "./ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=####@####.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=####
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

This worked perfectly when I created it, but now when I run `docker-compose up` the containers that get created are `pgadmin-1` and `pgdatabase-1`.

If I then run `docker-compose down`, and do a `docker ps` the output shows that no containers are running. However, if I run `docker-compose config --services` I get the following:

```
pgadmin
pgdatabase
```

Restarting Docker does nothing, and the issue occurs even if I delete all containers and all volumes from Docker Desktop.

`docker-compose start` returns `service "pgadmin" has no container to start`. If I run `docker-compose up` and then `docker-compose start pgadmin` I get no output from the command line. However, listing the active containers after doing this still only shows `pgadmin-1`. Running `docker-compose down` after these steps does not resolve the issue.

`docker rm -f pgadmin` returns `Error: No such container: pgadmin`.

`docker service rm pgadmin` returns `Error: No such service: pgadmin`.

`docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --renew-anon-volumes` just creates `pgadmin-1` and `pgdatabase-1` again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose: remove default suffix on container name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64976083/docker-compose-remove-default-suffix-on-container-name)

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Can you set the container name explicitly? e.g., `container_name: pgdatabase`

Comment: Using `container_name:` in the yml file does circumvent the naming problem, but I still have those two services when I run `docker-compose config --services`.

Answer (score 0):

The container and service names [are different things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565770/difference-between-service-and-container-in-docker-compose) in Docker Compose terminologies.

Given your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
services:
  pgdatabase:
    # ...
  pgadmin:
    # ...
```

The command `docker-compose config --services` lists the **service name**s, **BUT NOT** the **container name**s. A service name is a key you use in your `docker-compose.yml` file immediately under the key `services:`, e.g., `pgdatabase:` and `pgadmin:`.

Therefore, the output of `docker-compose config --services`:

```
pgadmin
pgdatabase
```

is **expected behavior**, whether any containers are running. Since the command `docker-compose config` only [parses your compose file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_config/), you can get the same output even when Docker itself is not running.

The default container name scheme of a container created by docker-compose is

```
<project>_<service>_<index>_<slug>
```

Assuming that your compose file is located in a directory `postgresql`, i.e.,

```
postgresql/docker-compose.yml
```

Then the default **container name**s created by `docker-compose` are:

- `postgresql_pgdatabase_1`
- `postgresql_pgadmin_1`

or in [Docker Compose V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69464001/docker-compose-container-name-use-dash-instead-of-underscore), they are

- `postgresql-pddatabase-1`
- `postgresql-pgadmin-1`

Of course you can override the default naming convention using the `container_name:` key in your Compose file.